# Backup windows 8.1 and restore in windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-backup

I shall be doing a clean install of window 8.1 on my laptop and then upgrading it to latest Windows 10. I want to take backup of all my win 8.1 data and then restore it into windows 10. Is there any inbuilt method available for that? If not, then what are the alternatives that I can opt for?

Edit: I am thinking about the system backup option available in the control panel's file history. So If I backup all the drives (including C), will I be able to restore the applications that I have currently installed?

Comment: What sort of data are you talking? What backup method did you have in mind? You can back up everything manually and restore it to wherever you like, on any OS, it's more a case of what programs you use and where they store their data.

Comment: @Jonno I have edited. Please feel free to ask anything more if you want

Comment: You should consider only backing up personal data and not system files.